# Why is this Sublime Text Grunt Build failing in Windows 7?

Tags: sublimetext2

Why is this Sublime Text Grunt Build failing in Windows 7?

```
{
    "cmd": ["grunt.cmd", "--no-color"],
    "path": "C:\\Users\\USER\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm;C:\\Program/ Files\\nodejs",
    "working_dir": "${project_path}"
}
```

Console says:
'node' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
[Finished in 0.1s with exit code 1]

Answer (score 0):

Try the following first:

```js
{
    "cmd": ["grunt.cmd", "--no-color"],
    "path": "C:/Users/USER/AppData/Roaming/npm;C:/Program\ Files/nodejs",
    "working_dir": "${project_path}"
}
```

If that doesn't work, try removing the `\` character between `Program` and `Files`. You don't need the `"selector"` argument at all, as that is used to specify the scope for the build system. `["Gruntfile.js"]` is not a valid scope.

As an alternative option, check out the [`Grunt`](https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/Grunt) plugin available via Package Control. I haven't used it myself, but it looks quite useful. It parses your `Gruntfile.(js|coffee)` file and adds the available tasks to the Command Palette, among other things. It directly reads your `PATH` variable, so as long as your node and npm directories are there, it should work quite well.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, Matt, though they didn't fix the issue. I did edit to remove the selector property. 

I do have the Grunt plugin, which is nice, but takes a few too many keystrokes to run a build, for my taste.

Comment: @ChristopherMeyers where is your `node.exe` located? Is it in `Program Files\nodejs` or `Program Files\nodejs\bin`?

Comment: "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe"